# Create a dictionary from values of a function, and using that for a graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, matplotlib

what I am trying to do is make a math function that takes input `n` and outputs `a`. I input a larger number and this goes through a `while loop`, subtracts one from that value, prints `a`, and repeats until a certain value of `n`. What I want to do is to put this into a dictionary, with `n` as a key and `a` as a value, and use that to graph via `matplotlib`. [Looking around a bit there](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html), it doesn't seem like it takes dictionaries, only lists or arrays, so it might be best to make separate lists of keys and values, then input that, and change markers and such. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def intan(n=3):
    a = 180 -(360/n)
    while n >= 3:
        print(a)
        n -= 1
        intan(n)

intan(4)
    '''Returns strange output of 90.0, 60.0, 90.0,
    instead of just the first two'''
```

As you can see, there is still a slightly odd error with the code where it cycles through the outputs more than once, but after some tinkering I can't quite figure out why that is. Thank you guys!

Update: The odd error is fixed by StephenRauch's helpful suggestion.

Comment: So, is your question how to return a dictionary, how to plot a dictionary in `matplotlib`, or why the code is returning 90.0 twice?

Comment: You have mixed up recursion and looping.  You likely need to do one or the other.

Comment: Move the `a=...` inside the while loop and remove the recursive `intan(n)` call.

Comment: @Colin my question(s) are mainly how to get a dictionary from the inputs and outputs of this function and plot that. The 90.0 error is secondary. (and now solved)

Comment: and @StephenRauch thanks for your fix! May I ask the difference between recursion and looping?

Comment: And the goal is to plot `180 -(360/n)` for n = 4 and 3?

Comment: Well the n=4 was just a test, I plan to see the results with different higher values of n, but yeah it stops at 3.

Comment: Looping is going in a circle to run the same code multiple times, recursion is calling the same function, before returning from a previous call to that function, to run the same code multiple times.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to split out the function from where you're going through values.  If `intan` is supposed to just return `180 -(360/n)`, just have it return that and do the looping elsewhere.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def intan(n):
    return 180 -(360./n)

n_values = range(4, 100)
plt.plot(n_values, list(map(intan, n_values)))
plt.show()
```

Equivalent `pandas` implementation

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


x = pd.Series(range(4, 100))
y = 180 - 360 / x

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, I love the solution, I seem to have overcomplicated it. However, when I run it I get: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`.

Comment: I fixed it for Python 3.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can tell messing more with PyPlot is going to be quite fun! :)

Comment: I'd recommend looking into `pandas`.  It makes a lot of things easier -- particularly aligning data.  I added the equivalent `pandas` implementation.

Comment: I'll be sure to look at that too!